# React Redux filter actions (generic sorting example)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have done a method to create a generic sorting reducer. The idea would be to call an action and filter it through a field in the action.meta.

The method is the following:

```
const initalStateSorting = {
  sortKey: undefined,
  sortOrder: "ASC"
}

const createSortingReducer = (endpoint) => {
  const sorting = (state = {}, action = {}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_SORT': {
        return {
          sortKey: action.payload.sortKey,
          sortOrder: action.payload.sortOrder
        }
      }
      case 'RESET_SORT': {
        return initalStateSorting
      }
      default:
        return initalStateSorting
    }
  }
  return (sorting)
}
```

With this method, I can create other generic reducers:

```
const photos = createSortingReducer('photos')
const text = createSortingReducer('text')

const sorting = combineReducers({
  photos,
  text
})

export default sorting
```

The problem with this generic method is that when I call the 'SET_SORT' action, I'm setting the sorting for the photos reducer and the text reducer.

Is there a way to  filter the input actions to the corresponding endpoint? Which will be the good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have decided to go with the following solution:

Here there are the action creators:

```
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions'

const createSorting = (endpoint) => {
  const setSort = (sort) => {
    return {
      type: `SET_SORT_${endpoint}`,
      payload: {
        sortKey: sort.sortKey,
        sortOrder: sort.sortOrder
      }
    }
  }
  const resetSort = () => {
    return {
      type: `RESET_SORT_${endpoint}`
    }
  }
  return {
    setSort,
    getSort,
    resetSort
  }
}


export const testSorting = createSorting('TEST')
```

And, the reducers might be created with each of the created key. The idea is that you will have an independent action receiver ( Maybe it will better to have the option to decide this in future versions of redux). Here is the example:

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux'
import { handleActions } from 'redux-actions'
import Immutable from 'immutable'

const SORT_ASC = 'asc'
const SORT_DESC = 'desc'
const defaultSortOrder = SORT_ASC

const initalStateSorting = {
  sortKey: undefined,
  sortOrder: defaultSortOrder
}

const test= handleActions({
  SET_SORT_TEST: (state, action) => {
    return {
      sortKey: action.payload.sortKey,
      sortOrder: action.payload.sortOrder
    }
  },
  RESET_SORT_TEST: (state, action) => {
    return initalStateSorting
  },
}, initalStateSorting)

const sorting = combineReducers({
  test
})

export default sorting
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the reducer you can create an object and set the value of corresponding specific endpoint reducer i.e for photos pass photos and set sorting corresponding to photos e.g -  in reducer create object like this

```
{ 
  ...state,{ 
        photos:{ 
        sortKey: action.payload.sortKey,
        sortOrder: action.payload.sortOrder
        }
    }
}
```

similarly do for text and then  you can first filter the value from state corresponding to endpoint and then set it's value so that you don't make multiple copies.

Comment: With this approach, I will end up with the following setSort: return {
          [endpoint]: {
            sortKey: action.payload.sortKey,
            sortOrder: action.payload.sortOrder
          }
        }. This will not allow me to filter the actions endpoint. The two endpoints will receive the set_state action

Comment: yes right and for filtering you can take corresponding endpoint from sorting reducer state like this .  For text you can do something like  state.sortingReducer.text.sortkey

Comment: I have the option to create two reducers, but this is a reducer creator. the state of both created reducers will be state.sortingReducer.endpoint.sortkey

Comment: yes right and this is in-fact better approach why create multiple reducers for this simple tasks.